# XCode 8 C++ Linked List Destructor error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, templates, linker

So I've been wrestling with this for the last two days. I need to create a LinkedList that's a template class for any . My current issue is that I can't test anything I've written. When I try and run it I get back a build error for the destructor saying:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "List342::~List342()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This happens even when using the built in ints data type. Here is my code, everything is in the .hpp file. The code isn't complete, I still have a few methods and operators to implement. I just can't seem to get any further right now since I can't test anything. If there's anything you guys can see that I'm just missing from staring at code for too long, I would greatly appreciate it.

** UPDATE I've implemented the functions and copied all the code to a new xCode project. I thought I was no longer getting the linker error, but it turned out I had a typo. Once I fixed the typo linker error returns. Here's the current error message followed by my current code:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, List342 const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, List342 const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
**

```
//
//  List342.hpp
//  Program 3 Linked Lists
//
//  Created by Chayse Summers on 10/30/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Chayse Summers. All rights reserved.


#ifndef List342_hpp
#define List342_hpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class List342
{

public:
    List342();
    List342(const List342 &target);
    ~List342();

    bool BuildList(string fileName);
    bool Insert(ItemType *obj);
    bool Remove(ItemType target, ItemType &result);
    bool Peek(ItemType target, ItemType &result) const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void DeleteList();
    bool Merge(List342 &input);

    //Still need to do op overloaders for +, +=, <<, ==, !=, =.
    const List342 operator +(const List342 &item)const;
    List342& operator +=(const List342<ItemType> &item);
    bool operator ==(const List342 &item) const;
    bool operator !=(const List342 &item) const;
    List342& operator =(const List342 &item);


    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &outStream, const List342<ItemType> &LL);



private:
    virtual void Print (ostream Out) const;
    struct Node
    {
        ItemType *value;
        Node *Next;
    };
    int count;
    Node *Head;
};

template <class ItemType>
List342<ItemType>::List342()
{
    cout<<"TestConstruct"<<endl;
    Head = NULL;
}

template <class ItemType>
List342<ItemType>::List342(const List342 &target)
{
    Head = NULL;
    *this = target;
}

//**Test BuildList.**
template <class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>::BuildList(string fileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ItemType temp;
    inFile.open(fileName);
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(!inFile.eof())
        {
            inFile>>temp;
            Insert(&temp);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//**Test Insert function.**
template <class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>:: Insert(ItemType *obj)
{
    Node *insertNode;
    ItemType *objValue;
    if(obj == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    insertNode = new Node;
    objValue = obj;
    insertNode->value = objValue;
    if(Head == NULL)
    {
        Head = insertNode;
        return true;
    }
    if(objValue < Head->value)
    {
        insertNode->Next = Head;
        Head = insertNode;
        return true;
    }
    Node *pNode = Head;
    while((pNode->Next != NULL)&&((pNode->Next)->value< objValue))
    {
        pNode = pNode->Next;
    }
    insertNode->Next = pNode->Next;
    pNode->Next = insertNode;
    count++;
    return true;

}

//**Test Remove function.**
template <class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>:: Remove(ItemType target, ItemType &result)
{
    Node *temp;
    if(Head == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(*(Head->value) == target)
    {
        temp = Head;
        Head = Head->Next;
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
        count--;
        return true;
    }
    Node *pNode = Head;
    while((pNode->Next != NULL)&&(*(pNode->Next->value) != target))
    {
        pNode = pNode->Next;
    }
    if(pNode->Next == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //    if(pNode->Next->value == target->value)
    //    {
    //        temp = pNode->Next;
    //        pNode->Next = pNode->Next->Next;
    //        delete temp;
    //        temp = NULL;
    //        return true;
    //    }
    //    return true;

    else
    {
        temp = pNode->Next;
        pNode->Next = pNode->Next->Next;
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
        return true;
    }

}

//**Test Peek.**
template <class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>:: Peek(ItemType target, ItemType &result) const
{

    if (Head != NULL)
    {
        Node *pNode;
        pNode = Head;
        while(pNode!=NULL)
        {
            if(*(pNode->value) != target)
            {
                pNode = pNode->Next;
            }
            else
            {
                result = *(pNode->value);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Null Pointer" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

//**Test isEmpty.**
template <class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>:: isEmpty() const
{
    if (Head == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}



//**Implement Merge.**
template <class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>:: Merge(List342 &input)
{
    Node *Left, *Right;
    ItemType *Value;
    if(input.Head != NULL)
    {
        if(Head != NULL)
        {
            if(this != &input)
            {
                Right = input.Head;
                if (!(*(Right->value) > *(Head->value)))
                {
                    input.Head = input.Head->Next;
                    if (!(*(Right->value) >= *(Head->value)))
                    {
                        Right->Next = Head;
                        Head = Right;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Value = Right->value;
                        delete Value;
                        delete Right;
                    }
                }
                Left = Head;
                while (input.Head != NULL)
                {
                    Right = input.Head;
                    if (Left->Next != NULL)
                    {
                        if (*(Right->value) > *(Left->Next->value))
                        {
                            Left = Left->Next;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            input.Head = input.Head->Next;
                            if (*(Right->value) < *(Left->Next->value))
                            {
                                Right->Next = Left->Next;
                                Left->Next = Right;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Value = Right->value;
                                delete Value;
                                delete Right;
                            }
                            Left = Left->Next;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Left->Next = Right;
                        input.Head = NULL;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Head = input.Head;
            input.Head = NULL;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//**This will be tested along with << overload.**
template<class ItemType>
void List342<ItemType>:: Print (ostream Out) const
{
    typename List342<ItemType>::Node *pNode;
    pNode = this->Head;
    if(pNode!= nullptr)
    {
        while(pNode->value != NULL)
        {
            Out << pNode->value;
            pNode = pNode->Next;
        }
    }

}

//**Test and correct if needed.**
template <class ItemType>
ostream& operator<< (ostream &outStream, const List342<ItemType> &LL)
{
    typename List342<ItemType>::Node *pNode;
    pNode = LL->Head;
    if(pNode!= NULL && pNode->Next != NULL)
    {
        while(pNode != NULL)
        {
            outStream << *(pNode->value);
            pNode = pNode->Next;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        outStream << "Null Pointer" << endl;
    }

    //LL.Print(outStream);
    return outStream;
}




template <class ItemType>
const List342<ItemType> List342<ItemType>::operator+ (const List342 &item) const
{
    List342<ItemType> result = *this;
    result += item;
    return result;

}


template <class ItemType>
List342<ItemType>& List342<ItemType>:: operator+= (const List342 &input)
{
    Node *Left, *Right, *Insert;
    ItemType *InsertValue;
    if(input.Head != NULL)
    {
        if(Head == NULL && input.Head != NULL)
        {
            *this = input;
            return *this;
        }
        Right = input.Head;
        if(!(Right->value > Head->value))
        {
            if(!(Right->value == Head->value))
            {
                Insert = new Node;
                InsertValue = new ItemType;
                InsertValue = Right->value;
                Insert->value = InsertValue;
                Insert->Next = Head;
                Head = Insert;
            }
            Right = Right->Next;
        }
        Left = Head;
        while(Right != NULL)
        {
            if(Left->Next != NULL)
            {
                if(!(*(Right->value) > *(Left->Next->value)))
                {
                    if(!(*(Right->value) == *(Left->Next->value)))
                    {
                        Insert = new Node;
                        InsertValue = new ItemType;
                        *InsertValue = *(Right->value);
                        Insert->value = InsertValue;
                        Insert->Next = Left->Next;
                        Left->Next = Insert;
                        Left = Left->Next;
                    }
                    Right = Right->Next;
                }
                else
                {
                    Left = Left->Next;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Insert = new Node;
                InsertValue = new ItemType;
                *InsertValue = *(Right->value);
                Insert->value = InsertValue;
                Insert->Next = Left->Next;
                Left->Next = Insert;
                Left = Left->Next;
                Right = Right->Next;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        return *this;
    }

}

template<class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>:: operator== (const List342 &Input) const
{
    Node *Left, *Right;
    if(Head != NULL && Input.Head != NULL)
    {
        Left = Head;
        Right = Input.Head;
        while(Left != NULL && Right != NULL)
        {
            if(Left->value != Right->value)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Left = Left->Next;
                Right = Right->Next;

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

template <class ItemType>
List342<ItemType>& List342<ItemType>:: operator= (const List342 &input)
{

    Node *Left, *Right, *Insert;
    ItemType *newValue;
    if (this != &input || input.Head != NULL)
    {
        this->DeleteList();
        this->Head = NULL;
        Head = new Node;
        newValue = new ItemType;
        newValue = input.Head->value;
        Head->value = newValue;
        Left = Head;
        Right = input.Head->Next;
        while(!(Right == NULL))
        {
            Insert = new Node;
            newValue = Right->value;
            Insert->value = newValue;
            Insert->Next = NULL;
            Left->Next = Insert;
            Left = Left->Next;
            Right = Right->Next;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        return *this;
    }

}

template<class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>::operator!= (const List342 &item) const
{
    return !(*this == item);
}


template <class ItemType>
void List342<ItemType>:: DeleteList()
{
    cout << "Deleting list...";
    Node *temp;
    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "...";
        temp = Head;
        Head = Head->Next;
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
        count--;
    }
    cout << "Done!" << endl;
}


template <typename ItemType>
List342<ItemType>::~List342()
{
    cout << "Destructor has run!" << endl;
    DeleteList();
}


#endif /* List342_hpp */
```

Comment: Is this code all the hpp file? Why is this there? #include "List342.hpp"

Comment: That was a typo, our professor asked us to move all the code from the cpp file into the hpp, I just missed that line. Still get the same error though. Thanks for catching it, I removed it from the above code as well.

Comment: Stop staring at the code and use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.  Also, you can't test this without properly implementing the entire rule of 3, i.e. **working** copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and implement those and see what happens. I guess I got caught up trying to test and make sure the code I already wrote is working. I can't seem to get the debug to work right now, I set break points and hit run and nothing happens. I still get the build failed and error message.

Comment: Ok so here's an update...
I went through and initiated all the methods, and also created a new project and files to which I copy and pasted the code. I no longer get that linker error, however now the call of this->DeleteList(); is illegal as it says that DeleteList() is not a member of the List342<Child> class. It's very strange, I don't see why this would be as DeleteList() is not a private member or anything. I've updated my code above to reflect the current version.

Comment: Another thing is that I can't locate the .exe file that is normally under Products folder in Xcode. Usually there is one there I can show in the finder, right now if I try that the finder just doesn't respond.